# Python assign tuple to set() without unpacking

Tags: python, set, iterable-unpacking

How can I assign a `tuple` to a `set` without the members being unpacked and added separately?

For example (python 3.9.11):

```
from collections import namedtuple
Point = namedtuple('Point', 'x y')
p = Point(5, 5)
set(p)
```

produces `{5}`, whereas I would like `{Point(5, 5)}`

Comment: You can't, that's what `set` is _supposed_ to do with an iterable. If you want a set of one Point, you need to wrap that point in a sequence, e.g. `set((p,))`. Or just use a literal, `{p}`.

Comment: post that as an answer, and I'll accept it gladly :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make a `set` from a specific number of individual values, just use a `set` literal:

```
{p}
```

If you must, for some reason, specifically use the `set` constructor, just wrap the item in question in some other container literal before passing it to `set`, e.g.:

```
set((p,))
set([p])
set({p})  # Maximal redundancy
```

but all of them will be slower and uglier than just using the `set` literal. The only time people typically would do this is in code written for ancient Python (from when `set` was introduced in 2.4 until 2.6, the `set` constructor was the only way to make a `set`; in 2.7 and higher, the `set` literal syntax was available).

---

Minor side-note: Be aware that `{}` is an empty `dict`, not a `set`. To make an *empty* `set`, you typically use `set()` (or `{*()}`, the one-eyed monkey "operator", if you're having fun). But as long as you have at least one item to put in the `set` literal, it works (it can tell it's a `set` because you didn't use `:` to separate key-value pairs).

Comment: worth the upvote if only for the 'one-eyed monkey' LoL

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Point = namedtuple('Point', 'x y')
>>> p = Point(5, 5)
>>> p
Point(x=5, y=5)
>>> s = set()
>>> s.add(p)
>>> s
{Point(x=5, y=5)}
```

Comment: The downvote is probably because this is a much wordier way of achieving what `{p}` does in 3 characters.

Comment: @user2357112: That may be, but `{p}` is only useful for the first/only item in the set - if you actually want to add more elements...

Answer (score -2):

You can wrap the tuple in another tuple, may ne something like this:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Point = namedtuple('Point', 'x y')
p = Point(5, 5)
s = set()
s.add((p,))  # Add the tuple (p,) to the set
print(s)  # Output: {(Point(x=5, y=5),)}
```

Comment: If they're calling `.add`, they don't need the wrapping to achieve their desired result. They only had it unpack the `namedtuple` contents because they passed it to the `set` constructor (equivalent to calling `.update`), but `.add` bypasses the issue entirely.